# How can I change the domain axis values Dynamically in AndroidPlot?

Tags: androidplot

Hi my problem is: I am doing an android app where there is a plot that plots data in real time that it reads from the bluetooh, I can add the y-values to the plot dynamically without any problem,but I'd like to change every second also the values of the domain, the plot plots a new data value every second so I'd like that the domain axis updates it's values every second. How can I do this can u please help me??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348413/how-to-change-domain-axis-labeles-in-android-plot).  You should be able to adapt this to your needs by injecting your own logic into the format(...) method.